# Django: Database returned an invalid datetime value. Are time zone definitions for your database and pytz installed

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I currently execute the following code:

```
statistics = Statistic.objects
.filter(id=1)
.annotate(timestamp=Trunc('timestamp_start','day', output_field=DateTimeField()))
.values('timestamp')
.annotate(usage_start = Min('usage_start'))
```

I have 1 record in that statisitc table, the value for timestamp_start is:

```
2016-12-22T06:00:00+02:00
```

I do have pytz installed. I'm running sqlite database. Any idea how to resolve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Removing the timezone info (+2:00) resolved it.